# Check is date is greater than today in Room database

Tags: android, sql, android-room

Hi I have a query where I order the list of products based on the product_end_date. I want to get only the list of products whose end date is greater than or equal to today,how can i do that in Room

here is my query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM product_data_table ORDER BY product_end_date ASC")
    fun getAllProductsOrderByEndDate(): LiveData<List<Product>>
```

I want to do

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM product_data_table WHERE product_end_date >= date('now') ORDER BY product_end_date ASC")
        fun getAllProductsOrderByEndDate(): LiveData<List<Product>>
```

I am not sure how to use `todays date` in where clause

please suggest

Edit

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_data_table")
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id")
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_name")
    var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_catagory")
    var catagory: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_end_date")
    var end_date: Date
)
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Can you share your `Product` entity and the type converters (if using any)?

Comment: @Sdghasemi i edited my question with the entity

Comment: And how do you convert `Date` to SQLite readable format like `INTEGER`?

Comment: to display it I do `product.end_date.toString()`

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783462/comparing-a-date-in-a-room-database

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("SELECT * from product_data_table WHERE DATE(product_end_date) >= DATE('now') ")
fun getAllProductsOrderByEndDate(): LiveData<List<Product>>
```